# CameraX can't initialize

Tags: android, android-camerax

I try to use CameraView. And I'm a beginner in Android. I read some articles and information on class but I am not able to make it works.
I have the following errors :

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: CameraX is not initialized properly. Either CameraX.initialize() needs to have been called or the CameraXConfig.Provider interface must be implemented by your Application class

Here is my code :

activity_main.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.camera.view.CameraView
    android:id="@+id/view_camera"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

MainActivity.java:

```
    package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.camera.camera2.Camera2Config;
import androidx.camera.core.CameraX;
import androidx.camera.core.CameraXConfig;
import androidx.camera.core.impl.CameraFactory;
import androidx.camera.core.impl.PreviewConfig;
import androidx.camera.view.CameraView;

import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraXConfig.Provider {

    private CameraView view_camera;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        view_camera = findViewById(R.id.view_camera);
        view_camera.bindToLifecycle(this);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CameraXConfig getCameraXConfig() {
        return Camera2Config.defaultConfig();
    }
}
```

And the manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The gradle file for app:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    def camerax_version = "1.0.0-alpha10"// Add the CameraX core dependency implementation
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"// Add the CameraX Camera2 API interop support dependency
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha06"
    // If you want to use the CameraX Extensions library
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.0.0-alpha06"
    // If you want to use the CameraX Lifecycle library
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.0.0-alpha03"
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The error is pretty clear

`CameraX.initialize() needs to have been called or the
CameraXConfig.Provider interface must be implemented by your
Application class`

neither of which you did

Comment: If I try to call CameraX.initialize() it says it can't be call outside of camerax package. And MainActivity.java implements CameraXConfigProvider in the MainActivitty.java. May be I do something wrong.

Comment: You do not implement `CameraXConfig.Provider` in your activity, you need to do it in your `Application` class of your app

Comment: Right. I add My application class but now I have the following errors that seems to be from the cameraX library. `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/camera/core/Preview$PreviewSurfaceProvider;
        at androidx.camera.view.CameraView.init(CameraView.java:199)`.

Comment: Find the issue I ha to use alpha06 version of cameraX. I will close this.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue with the latest alpha11 cameraX library, so downgraded to

```
// CameraX View class
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha10"
```

Also added the camera info parameter

```
preview?.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.createSurfaceProvider(camera?.cameraInfo))
```

Comment: Yes. This Solution Helped. Thanks Ravi!

Comment: Glad, I could be helped @RohitSharma

Comment: does CameraX support filter on Video while recording?

Comment: Had to rollback from from v1.1.0-alpha11 to v1.1.0-alpha10. Now it's working

Answer (score 3):

None of the solutions from here worked for me, and I'm on `1.0.0-beta08` version of CameraX. What worked for me was to make sure that I'm calling the statement

```kotlin
Preview.Builder()
    .build()
    .also {
        it.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.createSurfaceProvider())
    }
```

after the future from `ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(context)` gets resolved.

So while I was trying to save a reference to the preview in the fragment, I ended up with something like this:

```kotlin
private fun startCamera() {
    val context = requireContext()
    val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(context)
    cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
        val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
            .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
            .build()

        val preview = Preview.Builder()
            .build()
            .also {
                it.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.createSurfaceProvider())
            }

        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview)
    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

createSurfaceProvider() has been renamed to getSurfaceProvider():

```
preview?.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
```

Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63993443/3176753

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue with beta04 and had to add the camera2 dependency also:

```
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.0-beta04"
```

Comment: For Me was a similar issue, after updating androidx.camera:camera-view from version (1.0.0-alpha32) to version (1.1.0-beta01) I also had to update the remaining camera libs from version 1.0.2 to 1.1.0-beta01

Answer (score 1):

Please try these steps. I had the same issue and I fixed it like this.

1. Add the latest CameraX dependencies to your gradle:

   ```
   def camerax_version = "1.0.0-beta06"
   implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"
   implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
   implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${camerax_version}"
   implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha13"
   implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.0.0-alpha13"
   ```
2. Add `compileOptions` `JavaVersions` within `android{}` in gradle and sync now:

   ```
   compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }
   ```
3. Create a new Java class with the below attributes. Leave the rest as is:

   Name: `CameraXIntApplication` (You can give any name you like)
   Superclass: `android.app.Application`
4. Go to the `CameraXIntApplication` class you just created and create the `onCreate` method. Note: I had to manually create the `onCreate` method in this class and it was not there by default. However you might get it by default.
5. Inside `onCreate`, put the below code:

   ```
   CameraX.initialize(context: this, Camera2Config.defaultConfig());
   ```
6. Open up your Manifest.xml. in `<application>`, give your Java class the name you created. If `android:name` is not there, you can create it:

   ```
   <application
       android:name=".CameraXIntApplication"
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       >
   ```
7. From your main activity, remove these. They are not required any more:

   ```
   implements CameraXConfig.Provider from public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraXConfig.Provider
   ```

   and this:

   ```
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CameraXConfig getCameraXConfig() {
        return Camera2Config.defaultConfig();
    }
   ```

That's it. This should initialize the camera when your app gets opened.

Answer (score 0):

Non of all this suggestion doesn't help me. My PreviewView was on Fragment not in Activity.

In my case I have to add class MyApplication which implements CameraXConfig.Provider

```
public class MyApp extends Application implements CameraXConfig.Provider {
@Override
public CameraXConfig getCameraXConfig() {
    return CameraXConfig.Builder.fromConfig(Camera2Config.defaultConfig())
            //.setCameraExecutor(myExecutor)
            //.setSchedulerHandler(mySchedulerHandler)
            .build();
}
```

}

Next thing I got to do it was to change from `getInstance(this)` to:

```
cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

Full code:

```
private void startCamera() {
    Log.d(TAG, "startCamera: starting camera");
    cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {
        try {
            ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
            bindCameraPreview(cameraProvider);
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e)
            Log.e(TAG, "startCamera: Error during starting camera", e);
        }
    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()));
}

private void bindCameraPreview(@NonNull ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {
    Log.d(TAG, "bindCameraPreview: start");
    previewView.setImplementationMode(PreviewView.ImplementationMode.PERFORMANCE);

    Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
            .build();

    preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider());

    CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
            .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
            .build();

    Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)this, cameraSelector, preview);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My `camera-camera2` and `camera-lifecycle` libraries were using version `1.0.2` while the `camera-view` library was using `1.1.0-beta01`.

Changing them all to use `1.1.0-beta01` fixed it.

I'm guessing something in the upgrade from `1.0.2` to `1.1.0-beta01` causes an initialization error.